# What's the deal with Rohloff and Gates Carbon Drive?

Tags: rohloff, gates

Can someone explain to me why a Gates/Rohloff combination is so stonewalled? It's got warnings all over the kit that you cannot do an aftermarket conversion, that you need Rohloff to switch you from chain to belt (why?), that your frame apparently has to pass some stiffness test, et cetera. It never ends.

Reason I'm asking is that the parts for the front/rear CDX cogs for Gates are readily available on the market, and it seems like if your frame supports it, there should be a way to just attach them and ride. But evidently neither Rohloff nor Gates want you to do anything like that, preferring to keep this as some OEM option.

Don't get me wrong, I'm OK with chains, but why even bother selling the kit if people cannot use it?

Comment: Don't belt drives require a break in the frame? Adding this break would be risky and prompt a warning

Comment: @ChrisH holy cow, I think you're right! (well you can offset that with a snub wheel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rampant Guess: Given how much Rohloff likely values their reputation (the hubs are hailed for their longevity under poor conditions) they are likely being extra cautious as the set up might produce poor results under some conditions.

Gates belts require a lot of tension to operate correctly. This can be hard on hub bearings and could potentially twist a frame if is not designed for it. There is a lot going on inside a Rohloff hub, I suspect twisting could put important hub parameters out of specification, which could shorten the hub life. Being risk adverse to any tarnish on their reputation it sounds like they are trying to tightly control this potential problem.